# How do you use the Commander plugin in gedit?

Tags: gedit

This plugin is available from `gedit-plugins` package. Other than what its name and short description are, there are no other helpful info about the plugin usage.

Does anyone know how to use this plugin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Activate the commander plugin from `Edit -> Preferences ->Plugins Tab`, there check the commander plugin.

Now click `Edit -> Commander Mode` and you'll see a command prompt at the bottom.

[image: edit]

[image: menu]

[image: commander]

Here is an excerpt from the [Commander plugin page on Gnome Libraries](http://library.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-plugins-commander.html.en):

- See an overview of available commands - `Tab + Tab`
- Find a word within the current file - `/ foo` - *This will find the word foo.*
- Replace a word within the current file - `// foo bar` - *This will replace foo with bar.*
- Move the cursor to a certain line number in your file - `go [line number]` or just `g [line number]`
- Toggle the bookmark indicator for the current line - `bookmark` or just `b`

Comment: The link to the Commander plugin page seems to be down (404 error). Is there any other place to find full documentation on the plugin? The GitHub page of the project itself appears to have been abandoned for 11 years, and doesn't feature such documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this article](http://library.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-plugins-commander.html.en) about `gedit-commander` on the GNOME website; it should be really helpful. The [git-hub](https://github.com/alexkv/gedit-commander) home of the project also contains further information.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Commander plugin page is gone now, but you can still access the help text from the gedit menu, at least in v3.4.1: *Help -> Contents -> Configure and use gedit Plugins -> Additional gedit Plugins/Commander*.

Comment: Ok, when I checked this I was on 12.04LTS. Sadly, and not too surprisingly, it's gone from gedit since 14.04 (which uses gedit 3.10.4). Next time I'm on 12.04 I'll try and remember to grab the help text, although I think Nitin's answer probably covers most of it.